# sqlfuction to django method

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have this postgresql function. Can I convert this function to django-method?

I have implemented these functions in sql, but I would like to implement these functions so that they can be used in django or may I ask if there is a way to use the raw-query function separately in django?

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "pgcrypto";

DO $$ BEGIN
  CREATE DOMAIN SHORTKEY as varchar(11);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN duplicate_object THEN null;
END $$;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION shortkey_generate()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
  gkey TEXT;
  key SHORTKEY;
  qry TEXT;
  found TEXT;
  user_id BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  qry := 'SELECT id FROM ' || quote_ident(TG_TABLE_NAME) || ' WHERE id=';

LOOP

IF NEW.id IS NOT NULL THEN
  key := NEW.company_id;
  user_id := TRUE;

  IF length(key) <> 11 THEN
    RAISE 'User defined key value % has invalid length. Expected 11, got %.', key, 
length(key);
  END IF;
ELSE
  gkey := encode(gen_random_bytes(8), 'base64');
  gkey := replace(gkey, '/', '_');  -- url safe replacement
  gkey := replace(gkey, '+', '-');  -- url safe replacement
  key := rtrim(gkey, '=');          -- cut off padding
  user_id := FALSE;
END IF;

EXECUTE qry || quote_literal(key) INTO found;


IF found IS NULL THEN
  EXIT;
END IF;

IF user_id THEN
  RAISE 'ID % already exists in table %', key, TG_TABLE_NAME;
END IF;

END LOOP;

NEW.id = key;

RETURN NEW;
END
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run SQL commands on objects like this:

```
MyModel.objects.raw(
"""
    SQL-COMMANDS
"""
)
```

In migration files you can run:

```
migrations.RunSQL(
   """
       SQL-COMMANDS
   """
)
```

But it's generally not recommended to do that. I would recommend to transform this SQL script to Python/Django code.